# ASP.NET Ajax Toolbox Error Cannot Read property UI of undefined

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, toolkit

I am trying to learn how to use the Ajax Toolbox with my .net application. I added the toolbox via Manage NuGet Packages and added the following to my web.config file:

add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolKit" namespace="AjaxControlToolKit"

whenever I go to a page and try and add an element from the Ajax Toolkit I get an error message "Cannot read property 'UI' of undefined

If I try and add in the ToolkitScriptManager on the page I get an error "Only one instance of ScriptManager can be added to a page"

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Make sure you have the correct version of the AjaxControlToolkit for the version of .NET you are targeting.  They compile that for .NET 3.x and 4.x.  ToolkitScriptManager inherits from ScriptManager, so remove any ScriptManagers from your .aspx code.  If you have further questions, we need to see your .aspx code.

Answer (score 5):

Please make sure to have one script manager in the page.

I met with the same problem and able to solve it by adding toolkitscriptmanager with CombineScripts set to false.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="sriptmanger" runat="server" CombineScripts="false" />
```

cheers